# how to get image coordinate transformation in cv2.remap

Tags: opencv, image-processing

i have to do multiple remap in iterations, like, from xy to uv to mn etc.

I want to find the relationship between xy to mn, and do the remap only once.

but cv2.remap only returns remapped images, not coordinates. so I wonder if there is a way to get the equivalent map coordinates given every map.

```
u = x + dx
m = u + du = x + dx + d(?)
```

Comment: What do you think the contents of mapping table are?

Comment: I need to merge multiple tables to be as one

Comment: I'll answer for OP: maps suitable for remap are "pull", i.e. inverted. they specify the location in the source for every result pixel. forward transformations are difficult with such maps. that would require inverting the map (iterative process).

Comment: OP: your notation is weird. please clarify. this process does not involve "d"-anything.

Answer (score 0):

> from xy to uv to mn

With OpenCV's `remap()`, xy to uv part is as

`IMG_UV(u,v) = IMG_XY( (x,y)=Tbl1(u,v) )`

And also, uv to mn part is as

`IMG_MN(m,n) = IMG_UV( (u,v)=Tbl2(m,n) )`

So, xy to mn will becomes to as

`IMG_MN(m,n) = IMG_XY( (x,y)=Tbl1( (u,v)=Tbl2(m,n) ) )`

But, if you do this from only mapping tables (already sampled), `(x,y)=Tbl1( (u,v)=Tbl2(m,n) )` will require interpolation, etc.
Because `(u,v)=Tbl2(m,n)` may be float value and/or be outside position of `Tbl1`.

Therefore, creating the desired table(mn from xy) without unnecessary sampling in intermediate steps will be recommended.